# django - Extending `auth.models.User` and usering login, logout

Tags: django, django-authentication

If I create a `CustomUser` model which inherits from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, like so:

`in models.py`

```
class CustomUser(django.contrib.auth.models.User):
    customfield = TextField()
    ...
```

Should I still be able to use 
`django.contrib.auth.{authenticate, login, logout}` in the normal way? Do I have to make some additional configuration change? I know these methods only work on `User` objects, but technically my `CustomUser` is-a `User`.

Currently, `authenticate(username=u, password=p)` is always returning `None`, even with valid credentials.

Comment: Which Version of django are you using?

Comment: @Marc `Django==1.6.2`, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Django 1.5 (officially but it doesn't worked for me) and "stable" in 1.6 there is a functionality to extend the User model in a clean way.

At first:

-> Take care that you load the User model only via:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

-> Once you have built the database theres no easy way to change the User model. The database relations will break and Django / South isn't able to fix it.

-> third party modules have to be compatible with that new layout and refer in it's models to "get_user_model()", too.

You have to add some Code for the admin to respect your new model:
See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

To Override the model you need to inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    height = models.FloatField()
    ...
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth', 'height']
```

AbstractBaseUser provides you all attributes of the default user model. So you don't have to take care of email, username, first_name, last_name, password etc.
More info about overriding the user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser

In your settings link your new model:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customauth.MyUser'
```

Please read the whole [documentation of customizing the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/), there are some interesting hints for overriding the default manager, admin forms etc. Just remember that bigger changes in an existing project can be a big pain.

Comment: Can MyUser be used with the built-in groups or does that have to be modified too.  (ie is the AUTH_USER_MODEL definition enough to tie it together)?

Comment: Yes, just pass in your model the PermissionsMixin (find in django.contrib.auth.models) This mixin takes care of the model relations and methods

Answer (score 1):

A short overview:
- Extend models.AbstractUser
- Set AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py

All details can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model